# Experience editor does not show the empty placeholder before saving/refreshing the page

Tags: experience-editor, placeholders

We are using Sitecore 9.3 in our application and facing issue in experience editor.

When we add any component in empty placeholder in experience editor and then remove the component, we do not see the the empty placeholder. Now if we save the page or refresh the page we get the empty placeholder back. But it is expected to have empty placeholder immediately when we remove the component.  The empty placeholder div is missing.

[image]

There is no console error or error in log files. The issue is not specific to any rendering or any template.

Comment: This seems to a bug in the product itself, I suggest you to raise a Sitecore Support ticket.

Comment: It is working fine in another project which uses same sitecore version. So this may not be product related issue. Tried to create a test layout with nothing but main placeholder but still the issue persists. When the name of the placeholder is changed from "main"  to something else then it works as expected. Strange behavior.

Comment: Do you have JavaScript and CSS on the test layout? If yes, can you try to disable these and check if it works?

Comment: I have disabled all CSS and JSS. The test layout is having nothing except "main" placeholder.